# addAttributeToFilter on magento return incorrect

Tags: magento

I got a problem when overriden Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List class in magento. My goal is add some filter at Overriden Class. My Code

```
public function getLoadedProductCollection()
{
    $collection = parent::_getProductCollection();
    $collection->addAttributeToFilter('model',  array('eq' => 'coucu'));

    var_dump($collection->count()); // return 1 (incorrect)
    var_dump($collection->getData()); // return empty (correct)
    return $collection;
}
```

I need after filter will be don't have any product!

Answer (score 1):

Most of the time this is due to the collection being already loaded.
You have to know that Magento collection only load once (to save db access) because there is a flag `_setIsLoaded` on the underlaying `Varien_Data_Collection` that stop you to reload it.

What you can try to do is

```
public function getLoadedProductCollection()
{
    $collection = parent::_getProductCollection();
    var_dump($collection->isLoaded());
    return $collection;
}
```

If that does displays you a `true` that means you collection is already loaded and that your `addAttributeToFilter` won't ever be executed. And well it is going to be the case because, well the function is not called **`getLoadedProductCollection`** for no reason.

There is two ways to resolve this.
The best : override `setCollection` instead

```
public function setCollection($collection)
{
    $this->_productCollection = $collection;
    $this->_productCollection->addAttributeToFilter('model',  array('eq' => 'coucu'));
    return $this;
}
```

The not that good because then your collection would be loaded twice and surcharge your db :

```
public function getLoadedProductCollection()
{
    $collection = parent::_getProductCollection();
    $collection->clear(); 
    // this resets the _isLoaded flag
    /** @see Varien_Data_Collection::clear() */
    $collection->addAttributeToFilter('model',  array('eq' => 'coucu'));
    return $collection;
}
```